# Android App runs fine in Debug mode but crashes in Release

Tags: android

I'm developing an Android app to display the ground track of a satellite.
I have a custum view that override ImageView and the onDraw method.
In onDraw I have an heavy calculations

**My problem is that in Debug mode all goes ok.**
In release mode (run mode) after some seconds the App goes freezing (it seems in loop).
No benefit from changing to SurfaceView.

How i can do to find the problem ?
Is there a tool in Android Studio ?

Thanks in advance

Comment: Check the crash logs.

Comment: The problem is that Logcat and Adblogs doesn't display nothing..it seems in loop

Comment: So you will need to fall back on the time honored tradition of System.out.println( "" );